# Error looping through a loop and breaking when condition is met

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript, break

I am using jQuery to loop through an array and comparing each value with a model's user id. I will only display a specific text if a match is found.

```
$.each current_user.get('following_ids'), (i, e) =>
  console.log(@model.get('user')._id == e)
  if @model.get('user')._id == e
    @is_following = true
    //break from loop if condition is met
    return false
  else
    @is_following = false
    //else continue looping through
    return true

if @is_following
  $(@el).find('.user_info .follow a').text "following"
else
  $(@el).find('.user_info .follow a').text "follow"
```

However my code is not working, it always returns me "follow" text. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `current_user.get('following_ids')` is some sort of array of IDs. Two possibilities immediately come to mind:

1. `current_user.get('following_ids')` doesn't contain `@model.get('user')._id` so everything is working as expected.
2. You have a type problem. Perhaps the `following_ids` is an array of strings and `_id` is a number or vice versa.

Option **2** needs a little more explanation: CoffeeScript's `==` is converted to JavaScript's `===` so `1 == '1'` is false in CoffeeScript but true in JavaScript. This does make **2** a hidden and possibly surprising variant of **1** but it is special enough to be its own case.

Consider this simplified analogue of your situation:

```
$.each ['1','2','3'], (i, e) =>
    if 2 == e
        @is_following = true
        return false
    else
        @is_following = false
        return true
console.log @is_following
```

You'll get `false` out of that because `2 == '2'` is `false` is CoffeeScript: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/YsstH/

But, if we fix the types:

```
$.each [1,2,3], (i, e) =>
    # Only the array changes...
console.log @is_following
```

Then we get the `true` result that we're expecting: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/CxHXu/

---

In any case, since you're using Backbone, you have Underscore so you could just use [`_.any`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#any):

```
@is_following = _(current_user.get('following_ids')).any (id) => @model.get('user')._id == id
```

or better:

```
want_this_id  = @model.get('user')._id
@is_following = _(current_user.get('following_ids')).any (id) -> want_this_id == id
```

You'd still have to sort out the type problem though.

Comment: I wish I can upvote your answer multiple times. Thanks you hit the nail on the head! Also love your alternative solution, so much cleaner and efficient. Thanks alot!

Comment: @Zhen: No worries, sometimes I like puzzles :)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you're overwriting the result after you've found the match.  If you've found a match, there's no need to keep checking.

```
$.each current_user.get('following_ids'), (i, e) =>
  unless @is_following
    console.log(@model.get('user')._id == e)
    if @model.get('user')._id == e
       @is_following = true
      //break from loop if condition is met
      return false
    else
      @is_following = false
      //else continue looping through
      return true

if @is_following
  $(@el).find('.user_info .follow a').text "following"
else
  $(@el).find('.user_info .follow a').text "follow"
```

Comment: And for the record, `false` doesn't break -  `break` does.

Comment: For the record, `false` does break: ["We can break the `$.each()` loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return `false`.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: Yah that was what I read too, so I thought if there is a match , it should break